# Vertical Endless Slider in Figma

Tags: figma

I'm trying to make a vertical endless slider in Figma for an app and I run into a problem. The animation after the last slider is not transitioning smoothly. It keeps refreshing and clips.
https://www.figma.com/file/d0CEbOwSBFLQwNpdUNExMQ/Untitled?node-id=1%3A3
I think the problem is in the Interaction from imac-7 to imac-1. I tried different animations but its not working.

Answer (score 0):

To create smooth animations, you'll need the same layer names from one frame to the next. Using "Smart Animate" will take your Column 1 and Column 2 and try to match them with your next frame based on those group names.

Try creating 4 groups, and ensure you have all 4 of those groups in all of your frames to help the smart animate function detect the correct layers.

Also, check to see that all your prototype interactions are set to "Smart Animate". It looks like one of your interactions might be set to "Instant" instead.

Answer (score 0):

@Doc You can actually achieve this with just 2 frames, Just ensure you have the first slides on the frame twice... this will allow you to come back to the beginning and start again seamlessly.

See example here: https://www.figma.com/file/HVLmQECSb4GlhMJIwLWyJH/Tidal-Slider?node-id=0%3A1